# Firebase with WordPress instead of SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to create a WordPress Site with Firebase Database, not SQL, is that possible?
and can I do anything like SQL Database (add users, add product, add news, add post and received also...)

If that is possible can you tell me the steps and what should i do?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The WordPress application is designed to use a MySQL database, and none of the code that interacts with the database is compatible with Firebase.

Comment: I've left an answer, Jacob is right, but I suspect there's a reason you want this, and you're not actually interested in Firebase. E.g. you're hoping this solves another problem you didn't mention such as synchronising databases between multiple environments. You should ask about your problem and mention you considered firebase might be a solution, rather than asking about your solution, it's a class X Y Problem fallacy

Comment: I ask this question since I want to build a Flutter application (News app) that uses Firebase and I want the WordPress Website to be connected to this application with this action (Post news, update, delete, etc)

Comment: So I hope you can give me a better solution for that

Comment: maybe if a can use the same SQL Database in the app and the Wordpress site

Comment: using Firebase directly is not the only way to do it ( assuming it can be done at all ).  Synchronising firebase with your WP database, or the other way around is also possible. You can also bypass Firebase entirely and talk to the WordPress REST API

Answer (score 2):

No you can't use Firebase as your WordPress database out of the box, and the chances there is a plugin to implement this are astronomically low.

Your best hope is that you can find a plugin that lets you embed Firebase data or interact with Firebase, but that would still need to use MySQL/MariaDB for users/posts/etc, you can't replace the DB connection with a Firebase connection ( and why would you want to it would be awful for performance ).

Officially, only MySQL/MariaDB is supported, with experimental SQLite database support being worked on.

Sometimes 3rd party plugins exist for other database providers ( notably PostgreSQL ), extremely rare to see, and have compatibility problems with plugins, assuming they work with the latest WordPress. Notably they're all for SQL type databases and work by trying to adjust the SQL syntax to be compatible with another database.

Comment: I find a plugin but it cost, so I want to make sure its possible first.

Comment: If there's a plugin then yes it's possible, assuming the plugin author is legitimate. If it does not work then I would expect a refund. Note that sites hosted with firebase can't run PHP. Likewise there are a lot of plugins for integrating firebase, but they don't let you replace the MySQL/MariaDB part, rather they integrate Firebase alongside to show information from Firebase in a WP install that already has an SQL server setup, e.g. plugins that let you use firebase to login ( but still have the normal WP users table ). Replacing MySQL/MariaDB with Firebase though is something else entirely